# j2me google translate api

Tags: api, java-me, google-translate, midp, google-translation-api

I really need an example how to translate a text with google translate API v2.

I have implemented already the following:

```
String googleUrl="https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=<My Key>";
googleUrl+="&q=";
googleUrl+=urlEncode(txtFeedback.getString());
googleUrl+="&source=";
googleUrl+=System.getProperty("microedition.locale").substring(0, 2);
googleUrl+="&target=en";
HttpConnection googlAPI = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;

StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
googlAPI = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(googleUrl);


googlAPI.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
dis = new DataInputStream(googlAPI.openInputStream());
int ch;
while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1) {
    response.append((char) ch);
}


String tt = response.toString();
tt = tt.substring(tt.indexOf("{"));
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(tt);
params +=js.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations").getJSONObject(0)
              .getString("translatedText") + crlf;
```

but this code throws the ***Certificate exception: certificate was issued by an unrecognized entity***

it throws the exception on my real device **Samsung GT-S5230** as well as **Emulator**

Really need help.

If I do something wrong it would be great to get an example how to call the google translate API from j2me midlet.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look shows you are accessing a **https** url:

> String googleUrl="https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=";

using httpConnection

> googlAPI = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(googleUrl);

Change that to HttpsConnection

```
HttpsConnection googlAPI = null;
...
googlAPI = (HttpsConnection) Connector.open(googleUrl);
```

and let's see how it goes.

Comment: Hi Opeyemi, Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't help.